# Swedish lemmatization

Tags: nlp, tokenize, lemmatization

I am trying to find a lemmatizer for Swedish without any success. Does anyone know anything about this? I am aware for the WordNet in the ntlk package but that's for the English only.

Answer (score 0):

There's no Swedish model available for it yet (Norweigan is the closest), but keep an eye on Spacy, really easy to use and overall a great tool.

[https://spacy.io/usage/models][1]